# Dynamically load configuration variable for email

Tags: email, lumen

I am planning to use partner specific configuration for sending email from Lumen. Thus host, port, username, password etc will change from partner to partner

.env file these configurations are set to null as below

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

In the controller file, these values are updating values as below

```
config(['mail.host' => trim($data_list[0]->mailServerHostName),
                'mail.port' =>  trim($data_list[0]->mailServerPortNumber),
                'mail.username' =>  trim($data_list[0]->mailServerUsername),
                'mail.password' =>  trim($data_list[0]->mailServerPassword),            
                'mail.from.address' =>  trim($data_list[0]->emailFromAlias),
                'mail.from.name' => trim($data_list[0]->emailFromName) ]);
```

The values are updating properly. also print_r(config('mail')); will print the values. But while sending email, it is not taking the updated values...instead, it is taking the values from .env file.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Riyas

Comment: This issue is because, the new values for 'mail.from.address' and  'mail.from.name'  are not updating properly.  print_r(config('mail')) displays updated value in controller, but  it is not taking the updated values while sending email. May be need to pass these two parameters in a different way

We manged it with following code

Comment: Code in Library file
<pre><code>
config(['mail.host' => trim($data_list[0]->mailServerHostName),
        'mail.port' =>  trim($data_list[0]->mailServerPortNumber),
        'mail.username' =>  trim($data_list[0]->mailServerUsername),
        'mail.password' =>  trim($data_list[0]->mailServerPassword) ]);
</code></pre>

FromEmail  and FromName are moved to controller file

Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from($data['fromEmail  '], $data['fromName']);
    $message->to( $data['toEmail'] )->subject($data['subject']);
   
});